# Install Universal Packages for Azure Pipelines

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I am building pipelines with Azure DevOps and a Windows Self-hosted agent, I need my pipelines to create Universal Packages, I installed AzureCli, I’m able to call “az login” without errors and tried to install the extension: az extension add --name azure-devops –debug

After several proxy errors that were taken care of, I have a long log where it finds packages to install and at the end, fails with this message: cli.azure.cli.core.util : An error occurred. Pip failed with status code 1

Could I give you this log and you could help me find a solution ?

Here are the logs:

```
C:\>az extension add --name azure-devops --debug
Command arguments: ['extension', 'add', '--name', 'azure-devops', '--debug']
Event: Cli.PreExecute []
Event: CommandParser.OnGlobalArgumentsCreate [<function CLILogging.on_global_arguments at 0x03176300>, <function OutputProducer.on_global_arguments at 0x03357BB8>, <function CLIQuery.on_global_arguments at 0x0337BDF8>]
Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreCommandTableCreate []
Modules found from index for 'extension': ['azure.cli.command_modules.extension']
Loading command modules:
Name                  Load Time    Groups  Commands
extension                 0.007         1         6
Total (1)                 0.007         1         6
Loaded 1 groups, 6 commands.
Found a match in the command table for 'extension add'
Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreCommandTableTruncate [<function AzCliLogging.init_command_file_logging at 0x032CCAE0>]
az_command_data_logger : command args: extension add --name {} --debug
metadata file logging enabled - writing logs to 'C:\Users\myAccount\.azure\commands'.
Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreArgumentLoad [<function register_global_subscription_argument.<locals>.add_subscription_parameter at 0x03482810>]
Event: CommandInvoker.OnPostArgumentLoad []
Event: CommandInvoker.OnPostCommandTableCreate [<function register_ids_argument.<locals>.add_ids_arguments at 0x034827C8>, <function register_cache_arguments.<locals>.add_cache_arguments at 0x03496030>]
Event: CommandInvoker.OnCommandTableLoaded []
Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreParseArgs []
Event: CommandInvoker.OnPostParseArgs [<function OutputProducer.handle_output_argument at 0x03357C00>, <function CLIQuery.handle_query_parameter at 0x0337BE40>, <function register_ids_argument.<locals>.parse_ids_arguments at 0x03482FA8>]
urllib3.connectionpool : Starting new HTTPS connection (1): aka.ms:443
urllib3.connectionpool : https://aka.ms:443 "GET /azure-cli-extension-index-v1 HTTP/1.1" 301 0
urllib3.connectionpool : Starting new HTTPS connection (1): azurecliextensionsync.blob.core.windows.net:443
urllib3.connectionpool : https://azurecliextensionsync.blob.core.windows.net:443 "GET /index1/index.json HTTP/1.1" 200 595107
Candidates ['azure_devops-0.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl', 'azure_devops-0.17.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl', 'azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl']
Candidates ['azure_devops-0.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl', 'azure_devops-0.17.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl', 'azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl']
Candidates ['azure_devops-0.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl', 'azure_devops-0.17.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl', 'azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl']
Candidates ['azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl', 'azure_devops-0.17.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl', 'azure_devops-0.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl']
Choosing the latest of the remaining candidates.
Chosen {'downloadUrl': 'https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/releases/download/20200401.4/azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl', 'filename': 'azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl', 'metadata': {'azext.minCliCoreVersion': '2.2.0', 'classifiers': ['Development Status :: 4 - Beta', 'Intended Audience :: Developers', 'Intended Audience :: System Administrators', 'Programming Language :: Python', 'Programming Language :: Python :: 3', 'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4', 'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5', 'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6', 'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License'], 'extensions': {'python.details': {'contacts': [{'email': 'VSTS_Social@microsoft.com', 'name': 'Microsoft', 'role': 'author'}], 'document_names': {'description': 'DESCRIPTION.rst'}, 'project_urls': {'Home': 'https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-cli-extension'}}}, 'extras': [], 'generator': 'bdist_wheel (0.30.0)', 'license': 'MIT', 'metadata_version': '2.0', 'name': 'azure-devops', 'run_requires': [{'requires': ['distro (==1.3.0)', 'msrest (<0.7.0,>=0.6.0)', 'python-dateutil (==2.7.3)']}], 'summary': 'Tools for managing Azure DevOps.', 'version': '0.18.0'}, 'sha256Digest': '21fd9bf9c01a315184f11d7f709f354075118c298fd662472273cb003bfbe23e'}
Extension source is url? True
Downloading https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/releases/download/20200401.4/azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl to C:\Users\myAccount~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpka5oft6d\azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
urllib3.connectionpool : Starting new HTTPS connection (1): github.com:443
urllib3.connectionpool : https://github.com:443 "GET /Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/releases/download/20200401.4/azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl HTTP/1.1" 302 666
urllib3.connectionpool : Starting new HTTPS connection (1): github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com:443
urllib3.connectionpool : https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com:443 "GET /107708057/b9ebb400-7427-11ea-8122-6475470f4228?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20201112%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201112T161923Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=729defdef091c38adf8ed04d7b9a9af25ba70342b0ad06069d6ac7841f61a7be&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=107708057&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dazure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream HTTP/1.1" 200 852922
Downloaded to C:\Users\myAccount~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpka5oft6d\azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Validating the extension C:\Users\myAccount~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpka5oft6d\azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Checksum of C:\Users\myAccount~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpka5oft6d\azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl is OK
Validation successful on C:\Users\myAccount~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpka5oft6d\azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Executing pip with args: ['install', '--target', 'C:\\Users\\myAccount\\.azure\\cliextensions\\azure-devops', 'C:\\Users\\myAccount~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpka5oft6d\\azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl']
Running: ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI2\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--target', 'C:\\Users\\myAccount\\.azure\\cliextensions\\azure-devops', 'C:\\Users\\myAccount~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpka5oft6d\\azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl', '-vv', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--no-cache-dir']
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\myAccount~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-target-y9brf6t0
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\myAccount~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-6gr0ctui
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\myAccount~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gjbrmoh7
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Processing c:\users\myAccount~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpka5oft6d\azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil==2.7.3 (from azure-devops==0.18.0)
  1 location(s) to search for versions of python-dateutil:
  * https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/
  Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org
  https://pypi.org:443 "GET /simple/python-dateutil/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4638
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/fd/335326ddbac76e5598341c0a3bcfb8f03989d34beebb4065aee23f68b642/python-dateutil-1.4.tar.gz#sha256=d66403c6397be477d5c74d6a66a9dd45846a2f8d563fdd6f132ea02b2eb57d9c (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 1.4
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/50/0a3e33ba83cebfef5e14fd52c1d6f053870618b6e15cf3e99fd5b893b2c7/python-dateutil-1.4.1.tar.gz#sha256=74b615c6a55b4421187feba1633fc233e7c5ebdd7abe9b092447a32946823357 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 1.4.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/7c/df59c89a753eb33c7c44e1dd42de0e9bc2ccdd5a4d576e0bfad97cc280cb/python-dateutil-1.5.tar.gz#sha256=6f197348b46fb8cdf9f3fcfc2a7d5a97da95db3e2e8667cf657216274fe1b009 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 1.5
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/52/9c18dac21f174ad31b65e22d24297864a954e6fe65876eba3f5773d2da43/python-dateutil-2.1.tar.gz#sha256=4c44ec3f9ff057b8c7b4c78beca5fdd8710600ea9a1df42f31bfcbae2f059dee (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/75/c5/85d027471fa665f8c8b8eb0b925f9d84b4eee745a257b16de4957de99e81/python-dateutil-2.2.tar.gz#sha256=eec865307ebe7f329a6a9945c15453265a449cdaaf3710340828a1934d53e468 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.2
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/66/54/d561347dbfa0a1eeaf49a005da5fd71c0a0be8e4e2676f14775dd0097430/python-dateutil-2.3.tar.gz#sha256=2db67d8832f19332908b4b9644865ced34087919702140862093e347e95730e4 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.3
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/2d/296f3e43efda760722e3c4312b90eb2ae475cb7edd9c7eaba280b1ab2dd7/python_dateutil-2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=55a2a434a2fdb527bbda3abce8c12dbd244b2f4b00f6062ec4146d2884f37604 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.3
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/56/037f001409fdcaa4af06c8e8d83cb723334ead10b4b57c3c192b6de3e09d/python-dateutil-2.4.0.tar.gz#sha256=439df33ce47ef1478a4f4765f3390eab0ed3ec4ae10be32f2930000c8d19f417 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.4.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/65/1d4e38ecca8f0b599748e11cea20ab1e011206d0ef1cce098b16e41e1857/python_dateutil-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=b6f4f95d6ed922c947bf22b15f55ff29e7cf57281975ee01988450182bf6e20c (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.4.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9c/b0/5948496efa852dfa78751c3f494f57fa01bfc453b4a7b7b47b0c2e0b6a80/python-dateutil-2.4.1.post1.tar.gz#sha256=aa9bdbd60c395db90204609f1fb5aeb3797870f65c09f04f243476d22f8f4615 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.4.1.post1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/c4/d9e410b1641e210262123f49619070e46da2a7ede334cf6b6fb3db5ee985/python-dateutil-2.4.1.post1.zip#sha256=71357959bd98cbf425a6f5c5632826b548cb09d0ff3272a3565322f8aba58088 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.4.1.post1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/fe/45044dfa6bfa6ff18ddfe1df85fbf01d333c284b94e8c9a02fe12241c8cf/python-dateutil-2.4.1.tar.bz2#sha256=a9f62b12e28f11c732ad8e255721a9c7ab905f9479759491bc1f1e91de548d0f (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.4.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c4/f5/f7e7edb5691268519f703172e25168a149b861d13c8e0993f9e9d990632d/python_dateutil-2.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=75bff83d2aeacfef8bb354cd1416cc04e65cff7bd6cd46a95de9dfccf0a254fd (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.4.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/ff/5eaa688dd8ce78913f47438f9b40071a560126ac3e95f9b9be27dfe546a7/python-dateutil-2.4.2.tar.gz#sha256=3e95445c1db500a344079a47b171c45ef18f57d188dffdb0e4165c71bea8eb3d (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.4.2
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/75/666cd70de6a70cc7c6560429340ee7ef08196c93f552428983a808423755/python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=2ae63cf475f0bd049b722fac20813d62aedc14957dd5a3bf00d120d2b5404460 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.4.2
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/d3/7800c2560d81f112417d245468b8c8d71a068d98cd13c3c14f193a297036/python-dateutil-2.5.0.tar.gz#sha256=c1f7a66b0021bd7b206cc60dd47ecc91b931cdc5258972dc56b25186fa9a96a5 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.5.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/2d/b5ceb7162be2c33c60cdf8b5970d360b41bb16a8cf83e632fca876846d09/python-dateutil-2.5.0.zip#sha256=03e9f05568c08a2f5e56bd5488c33c440a7e2c150a83a82e3c074475204a4a84 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.5.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/2c/1e76d08cbfb4d81faa4ab9995ed5d3ac45bd380da32df1733530dfdd8123/python_dateutil-2.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=3615baa560c215466332b78d1cfbc1214ff23dad8e0d8c0e473e03640007c167 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.5.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/6b/f3a920258ea1237d091b4a06aa0e527fa3ab76ede5875745425851e3d4c7/python-dateutil-2.5.1.tar.gz#sha256=40d1bc468c7df50aff9e7a12c14687f9180efcff86900ee2963f9f2c13b5d7a9 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.5.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/f8/3c03f8e9dbcfc803d7eb26bab2b2009ac438db7e8a89e8ebc44bfc59c6e1/python-dateutil-2.5.1.zip#sha256=43ab4f14887c9f7731032f437fe09c9adfe857e4eedc49cf899526a02c622618 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.5.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/c0/42f05312d33e36196c52225f6859a02baa66dae1cee34e9a6967910ba8a5/python_dateutil-2.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=3e1b429759b8c85f9c3c8e7349c74f1778ebbec1f60c095d5825db0b047eeae0 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.5.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/b7/923674117d83465c0ccab5d5fa1b66caba59d6fa7428089fd2470a1e29cd/python-dateutil-2.5.2.tar.gz#sha256=063907ef47f6e187b8fe0728952e4effb587a34f2dc356888646f9b71fbb2e4b (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.5.2
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/2a/03c4ea9e9502231ac4a619314b2b28a90f0aeec425efe2bd4c44d0ff8765/python-dateutil-2.5.2.zip#sha256=8a3f2c1d5bea698ea76435dd22352a5c0d7b95a4ff759c0ff87f974432b3c7bf (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.5.2
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/f8/88de2335cf6162be0b5c165b3e229267fe3c522ffa9464ffb424359ba682/python_dateutil-2.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=5187ca69bb0a9de482cc5e1d247460b8b62a82fdaf455a13749087094b87754c (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.5.2
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3e/f5/aad82824b369332a676a90a8c0d1e608b17e740bbb6aeeebca726f17b902/python-dateutil-2.5.3.tar.gz#sha256=1408fdb07c6a1fa9997567ce3fcee6a337b39a503d80699e0f213de4aa4b32ed (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.5.3
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/9f/ba2b6aaf27e74df59f31b77d1927d5b037cc79a89cda604071f93d289eaf/python-dateutil-2.5.3.zip#sha256=9d94861f04ce14f9a3d835206067c889b8f1244f1415035dadcf9c10066adf04 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.5.3
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/68/9eadc96f9899caebd98f55f942d6a8f3fb2b8f8e69ba81a0f771269897e9/python_dateutil-2.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=598499a75be2e5e18a66f12c00dd47a069de24794effeda4228bfc760f44f527 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.5.3
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/fc/39a3fbde6864942e8bb24c93663734b74e281b984d1b8c4f95d64b0c21f6/python-dateutil-2.6.0.tar.gz#sha256=62a2f8df3d66f878373fd0072eacf4ee52194ba302e00082828e0d263b0418d2 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.6.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/95/8e/71125f3f24771f50e630b5a6fa9fd209a9f167dcbc3aad65a48cb3dd5694/python-dateutil-2.6.0.zip#sha256=3acbef017340600e9ff8f2994d8f7afd6eacb295383f286466a6df3961e486f0 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.6.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/8b/275015d7a9ec293cf1bbf55433258fbc9d0711890a7f6dc538bac7b86bce/python_dateutil-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=537bf2a8f8ce6f6862ad705cd68f9e405c0b5db014aa40fa29eab4335d4b1716 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.6.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/bb/f1db86504f7a49e1d9b9301531181b00a1c7325dc85a29160ee3eaa73a54/python-dateutil-2.6.1.tar.gz#sha256=891c38b2a02f5bb1be3e4793866c8df49c7d19baabf9c1bad62547e0b4866aca (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.6.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/0d/7ed381ab4fe80b8ebf34411d14f253e1cf3e56e2820ffa1d8844b23859a2/python_dateutil-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=95511bae634d69bc7329ba55e646499a842bc4ec342ad54a8cdb65645a0aad3c (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/), version: 2.6.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/1d/64a3b1c30842ecf0518af93ed123e5064559e588aebdcae0a59831dee642/python-dateutil-2.7.0.tar.gz#sha256=8f95bb7e6edbb2456a51a1fb58c8dca942024b4f5844cae62c90aa88afe6e300 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*), version: 2.7.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/c5/3449988d33baca4e9619f49a14e28026399b0a8c32817e28b503923a04ab/python_dateutil-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=07009062406cffd554a9b4135cd2ff167c9bf6b7aac61fe946c93e69fad1bbd8 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*), version: 2.7.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/f5/d81ec46577350dcd96a26885d418969cd2b07c7d8c78e24e25c10bfc5c6f/python-dateutil-2.7.1.tar.gz#sha256=14eb44faa298942c6385636bfd76bd5c21361632cf8ebc9c20d63fd00f6a069f (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*), version: 2.7.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/95/27/d6be8938e2cd9c956c2c6c0b3253e1c62d6db29a52b477943da3c3ec728c/python_dateutil-2.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=6c0e72580272b561d8594362ab0e6b5b2191c703982150fc06ed45f7fae725be (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*), version: 2.7.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/39/4da7c2dbc4f023fba5fb2325febcadf0d0ce0efdc8bd12083a0f65d20653/python-dateutil-2.7.2.tar.gz#sha256=9d8074be4c993fbe4947878ce593052f71dac82932a677d49194d8ce9778002e (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*), version: 2.7.2
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0c/57/19f3a65bcf6d5be570ee8c35a5398496e10a0ddcbc95393b2d17f86aaaf8/python_dateutil-2.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=3220490fb9741e2342e1cf29a503394fdac874bc39568288717ee67047ff29df (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*), version: 2.7.2
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a0/b0/a4e3241d2dee665fea11baec21389aec6886655cd4db7647ddf96c3fad15/python-dateutil-2.7.3.tar.gz#sha256=e27001de32f627c22380a688bcc43ce83504a7bc5da472209b4c70f02829f0b8 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*), version: 2.7.3
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/f5/af2b09c957ace60dcfac112b669c45c8c97e32f94aa8b56da4c6d1682825/python_dateutil-2.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=1adb80e7a782c12e52ef9a8182bebeb73f1d7e24e374397af06fb4956c8dc5c0 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*), version: 2.7.3
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/15/37f2e39504a98ec4b3eba8c9a61755dd5374388201ee60d1ae5b8e7a3d09/python-dateutil-2.7.4.tar.gz#sha256=2f13d3ea236aeb237e7258d5729c46eafe1506fd7f8507f34730734ed8b37454 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*), version: 2.7.4
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/e9/b02e8a1a8c53a55a4f37df1e8e111539d0a3e76828bcd252947a5200b797/python_dateutil-2.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=f7cde3aecf8a797553d6ec49b65f0fbcffe7ffb971ccac452d181c28fd279936 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*), version: 2.7.4
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/01/68747933e8d12263d41ce08119620d9a7e5eb72c876a3442257f74490da0/python-dateutil-2.7.5.tar.gz#sha256=88f9287c0174266bb0d8cedd395cfba9c58e87e5ad86b2ce58859bc11be3cf02 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*), version: 2.7.5
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/68/d87d9b36af36f44254a8d512cbfc48369103a3b9e474be9bdfe536abfc45/python_dateutil-2.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=063df5763652e21de43de7d9e00ccf239f953a832941e37be541614732cdfc93 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*), version: 2.7.5
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ad/99/5b2e99737edeb28c71bcbec5b5dda19d0d9ef3ca3e92e3e925e7c0bb364c/python-dateutil-2.8.0.tar.gz#sha256=c89805f6f4d64db21ed966fda138f8a5ed7a4fdbc1a8ee329ce1b74e3c74da9e (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*), version: 2.8.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=7e6584c74aeed623791615e26efd690f29817a27c73085b78e4bad02493df2fb (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*), version: 2.8.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/be/ed/5bbc91f03fa4c839c4c7360375da77f9659af5f7086b7a7bdda65771c8e0/python-dateutil-2.8.1.tar.gz#sha256=73ebfe9dbf22e832286dafa60473e4cd239f8592f699aa5adaf10050e6e1823c (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/) (requires-python:!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,>=2.7), version: 2.8.1
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/70/d60450c3dd48ef87586924207ae8907090de0b306af2bce5d134d78615cb/python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=75bb3f31ea686f1197762692a9ee6a7550b59fc6ca3a1f4b5d7e32fb98e2da2a (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/) (requires-python:!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,>=2.7), version: 2.8.1
  Using version 2.7.3 (newest of versions: 2.7.3)
  Created temporary directory: C:\Users\myAccount~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-kit5x3j7
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): files.pythonhosted.org
  https://files.pythonhosted.org:443 "GET /packages/cf/f5/af2b09c957ace60dcfac112b669c45c8c97e32f94aa8b56da4c6d1682825/python_dateutil-2.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl HTTP/1.1" 302 0
  Starting new HTTP connection (1): wsg-proxy.myCie.com
  http://wsg-proxy.myCie.com:443 "GET http://nnn.n.n.nnn:nnnnn/cgi-bin/blockpage.cgi?ws-session=18446744073119692426 HTTP/1.1" 200 3212
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/f5/af2b09c957ace60dcfac112b669c45c8c97e32f94aa8b56da4c6d1682825/python_dateutil-2.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Downloading from URL https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/f5/af2b09c957ace60dcfac112b669c45c8c97e32f94aa8b56da4c6d1682825/python_dateutil-2.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=1adb80e7a782c12e52ef9a8182bebeb73f1d7e24e374397af06fb4956c8dc5c0 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*)
Collecting distro==1.3.0 (from azure-devops==0.18.0)
  1 location(s) to search for versions of distro:
  * https://pypi.org/simple/distro/
  Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/distro/
  https://pypi.org:443 "GET /simple/distro/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
  http://wsg-proxy.myCie.com:443 "GET http://nnn.n.n.nnn:nnnnn/cgi-bin/blockpage.cgi?ws-session=1893168779 HTTP/1.1" 200 3212
  Analyzing links from page http://nnn.n.n.nnn:nnnnn/cgi-bin/blockpage.cgi?ws-session=1893168779
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement distro==1.3.0 (from azure-devops==0.18.0) (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for distro==1.3.0 (from azure-devops==0.18.0)
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 291, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 103, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 257, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 210, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 245, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 307, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 533, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for distro==1.3.0 (from azure-devops==0.18.0)

Command '['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI2\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--target', 'C:\\Users\\myAccount\\.azure\\cliextensions\\azure-devops', 'C:\\Users\\myAccount~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpka5oft6d\\azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl', '-vv', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--no-cache-dir']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Pip failed so deleting anything we might have installed at C:\Users\myAccount\.azure\cliextensions\azure-devops
cli.azure.cli.core.util : An error occurred. Pip failed with status code 1. Use --debug for more information.
An error occurred. Pip failed with status code 1. Use --debug for more information.
Event: Cli.PostExecute [<function AzCliLogging.deinit_cmd_metadata_logging at 0x032CCC00>]
az_command_data_logger : exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

**To solve this problem, you need to upgrade your python to required version.**

(better to 3.7 not latest version, because azure-devops-cli extension use python 3.7 instead of latest because 3.8 has issues )

---

The **useful message** in your log:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement distro==1.3.0 (from azure-devops==0.18.0)
Found link ........... (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*), version: 2.7.0
...
```

From the [distro package documents](https://distro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#os-release-file) we can see,

> The distro package is supported on **Python 2.7**, **3.4+** and **PyPy**, and on
> any Linux or *BSD distribution that provides one or more of the data
> sources used by this package.

But in [Azure DevOps CLI extension for Azure CLI 0.18.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/releases), we can see

> **Changes:**
> **Remove** python 2.7 support

Comment: Many thanks !  I installed 3.7 using python-3.7.0-amd64.exe to C:\Python.

Comment: My REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE variable was already set to a file provided to me by security team.

Comment: Now, I have this: No matching distribution found for msrest<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 (from azure-devops==0.18.0)

Comment: I noticed it mentions to run from the Azure SDK folder:   Command '['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI2\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--target', 'C:\\Users\\myAccount\\.azure\\cliextensions\\azure-devops', 'C:\\Users\\myAccou~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpklii34qm\\azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl', '-vv', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--no-cache-dir']' returned non-zero exit status 1.      Should I have updated the version of Python in Azure SDK instead of installing in C:\Python ? Should I set a variable to tell it where to find latest version of Python ?

Comment: @ClaudeVernier ,sorry I didn't reproduce your case. You could check the python version under Azure SDK first, if it doesn't match the required version, then you need update it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I now end up with Python twice on my agent.    On the agent, I tried copying the content of C:\Python37 to C:\...\Microsoft SDKs`\Azure\CLI2 but that broke the agent, I had to rollback.         I'm sorry I'm so new at Python,   I have found that the agent's version of Python is 3.6.6.     Please note that the agent has limited access to Internet, if there was an offline package I could copy to the server and run it there to update the agent's version, it would be useful   :)

Comment: Hello, I’m sorry as it seems I was unclear.        I installed Powershell 3.7 on my agent but when installing AzureCLI, it still try to install this component: No matching distribution found for msrest<0.7.0,>=0.6.0.       I understand AzureCLI doesn’t use the Powershell I installed but still the one it has internally.       I tried to copy the files from Powershell 3.7 over the version in my agent but that broke the agent so I rolled back.  At the end, I still can’t install AzureCLI Devops extension, I am about to give up using Universal Packages on my self hosted agent behind a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

As a troubleshooting, you can try the following steps:

1.Browse to the file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem.

2.Edit the file and add the certs in Base-64 format that is part of
the cert chain that takes you to https://pypi.org/simple/distro/.

3.Run the following command to set the CA Bundle environment variable
to this file.

```
setx REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem" /M
```

Here is a [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122231/pip-error-while-installing-azure-cli-extension-behind-proxy) with similar issue you can refer to.